# C++ Inheritance Exercise

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
      Class One : public Two
        {
        public:
           One()
           {
              Three three;
              cout << "something";
           }
        private:
           Four _four;
       };
```

I have to display a sentence: "One Two Three Four Five Six Seven" and class One have to remain as it is. Every class can't display more than one word in her constructor and destructor.

So... i've figured out that my base class is Class Four. I've also made constr. & destr. in every class and tried to write something in their bodies but thats what ive got on output:

```
Class Four Constructor:
Class Three Constructor:
Class Two Constructor:
Class Four Constructor:
Class Four Constructor:
Class Three Constructor:
Class One Constructor:
Class Three Destructor:
Class Four Destructor:

DESTRUCTION:
Class One Destructor:
Class Four Destructor:
Class Two Destructor:
Class Three Destructor:
Class Four Destructor:
```

my main function:

```
int main()
{
 One one; //<----  it also have to remain
 cout << endl;
 cout << "DESTRUCTION:\n";
}
```

I've read a few articles about inheritance but still have no idea how to display words in classes constr. & destructors but dont do it twice or more even if i create objects of these classes like it is done in class One.

P.S Sorry for gramma and other mistakes ;)

Comment: *"something"* is not shown in the output - what are you supposed to have instead of `cout << "something"` in the "real" exercise? And does *"One Two Three Four Five Six Seven"* need to appear before *"DESTRUCTION:"* in the output? And can you use more classes than the 4 mentioned above?

Comment: "something" should look like "Class Four Constructor: ONE", "Class One Destructor: SIX" etc.
"DESTRUCTION" can be deleted, i created it to see whats goin on ;)
and i just have to display them, no matter where

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include that correct, exact, definition of class One. I can't figure what you wish to accomplish from your comment and solving your question is currently not possible given "cout << "something"

Comment: +1 for actually tagging this as homework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we can deduce, based solely on the known definition of `One` (and my remembrance of C++ construction rules, which may not be 100% accurate :-), not taking into account any additional possible inheritance relationships between the classes:

1. the output of `Two()` (being the base class constructor) comes before the output of all other constructors,
2. the output of `Four()` (belonging to a member of the derived class) comes next,
3. then the output of `Three()` (a local object within the `One()` constructor),
4. then the output of `One()` itself,
5. then the output of `~Three()` (being a local variable, it goes out of scope when returning from `One()`).

And here we have our shiny `One` object constructed. Since there is not much we can do with it, let's destroy it! Note that all objects are destroyed exactly in the opposite of their order of construction; this is a fundamental C++ rule. Thus

1. first comes the output of `~Four()` (since members are destroyed before their owner),
2. (then would come the output of the nonexistent `~One()`, as the derived portion of the class is destroyed before its base part),
3. then the output of `~Two()` as the base part is destroyed last.

This gives you exactly seven possible numbers to output, thus you need no additional base classes or members anywhere. Just put the right numbers into the output of the right constructors & destructors :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this as homework, so I'm not going to tell you the answer...

This exercise seems to be aimed at helping you understand the order in which constructors and destructors are called. Since you can only use class inheritance, member variables, constructors and destructors, they are your only mechanisms for determining program flow and therefore the ordering of output

Some questions:

- Which has its body executed first, a
  derived class constructor or a base
  class constructor? What about destructors?
- Is the constructor for a member
  variable executed before the
  constructor for the containing class?
  What about the destructors?

I suggest starting with a simple example. Two classes, each with a constructor and destructor, one subclassing from the other. Print something in each function and and look at the ordering. Then add another class an make it a member variable. What happens?

Since, you have to output an odd number of words, one class will have to print only in its constructor or destructor but not both.

Btw, in your question class Four is not the base class.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's done :]
Thank you for your replies, especially Péter Török :)

```
class Two
{
public:
    Two()
    {
        cout << "Class Two Constructor: ONE" << endl;
    }
    ~Two()
    {
        cout << "Class Two Destructor:" << endl;
    }
};

class Three
{
public:
    Three()
    {
        cout << "Class Three Constructor: THREE" << endl;
    }
    ~Three()
    {
        cout << "Class Three Destructor: FIVE" << endl;
    }
};

class Four
{
public:
    Four()
    {
        cout << "Class Four Constructor: TWO" << endl;
    }
    ~Four()
    {
        cout << "Class Four Destructor: SEVEN" << endl;
    }
};


class One: public Two
{
public:
    One()
    {
        Three Three;
        cout << "Class One Constructor: FOUR" << endl;
    }
    ~One()
    {
        cout << "Class One Destructor: SIX" << endl;
    }
private:
    Four _Four;
};
```

and output:

```
Class Two Constructor: ONE
Class Four Constructor: TWO
Class Three Constructor: THREE
Class One Constructor: FOUR
Class Three Destructor: FIVE

DESTRUCTION:
Class One Destructor: SIX
Class Four Destructor: SEVEN
Class Two Destructor:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to figure out the order in which constructors are called. When you invoke a constructor, the constructor of the super class executes first (Note that I am more comfortable with Java than C++ so be careful here). So if One inherits from Two which inherits from Three and you invoke the constructor of One then the order would be: Three, Two, One.

Answer (score 0):

Also understand this -

From Standard docs, Delete,

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different
>   from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.